# How to get extract for dynamodb which my email exists and updated by last 1 hour using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have dynamodb entries like below, here name is partition key, email is GSI

```
{
Name: "abc"
Description:"dfs",
'email': a@g.com,
'updatedAt': '2023-03-16 04:32:20.855678'}
```

How to retrieve all the item from dynamo using boto3 condition is below

1. email exists in the table
2. updatedAt should be last `1 hour`

```
table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
result = table.scan()
```

Need to give the filterexpression where email exists for all the dynamodb enries which updatedAt is last 1 hour

As mentioned I need all the entries in db which satisfy above criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that email is GSI, which I assume that your email attribute is the GSI PK. To make things even more efficient, you should make the email GSI partition key and updatesAt as sort key.

#### 1. GSI with `email` as PK and `updatedAt` as SK

**Most Efficient**

```
hour_ago = <calc time>
response = table.query(            
   IndexName='my-index-name',
   KeyConditionExpression=Key('email').eq('a@g.com') & Key('updatedAt').gt(hour_ago),     
)
```

#### 2. GSI with `email` as PK

**Efficient, but could be better**

```
hour_ago = <calc time>
response = table.query(            
   IndexName='my-index-name',
   KeyConditionExpression=Key('email').eq('a@g.com'),     
   FilterExpression=Attr('updatedAt').gt(hour_ago)
)
```

#### 3. Sparse GSI with Scan

```
hour_ago = <calc time>
response = table.scan(            
   FilterExpression= Attr('updatedAt').gt(hour_ago),
   IndexName='my-index-name',
)
```

As you mention you want all the items where the email exists, then you can use your index as a sparse index, as email is your partition key for the index you know it exists if them item is in the index. This allows you to do a scan with FilterExpression.

Comment: Hi, as in the question i need all the items in dynamdb table which email id exists and last updated before 1 hour'

Comment: Option 3 will solve your problem.

Comment: In this LastEvaluationKey has to be there?

Comment: Only if you have more than 1MB of data.